# With autofac, what is the difference in the two decorator patterns?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

What is the difference between the two above registrations?

```
builder.RegisterDecorator<IHeaderMappingRepository>(
    (c, inner) => new CachedHeaderMappingRepository(inner), 
    fromKey: "headerMappingRepository");
builder.RegisterType<SqlHeaderMappingRepository>()
    .Named<IHeaderMappingRepository>("headerMappingRepository");
```

and

```
builder.Register(c => new CachedHeaderMappingRepository(
    c.Resolve<SqlHeaderMappingRepository>()))
    .As<IHeaderMappingRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<SqlHeaderMappingRepository>().AsSelf();
```

Answer (score 0):

Theses two code sample are quite similar.

the only difference is that the first one use named resolution whereas the second use explicit resolution. With the second code sample, if you want to use another `IHeaderMappingRepository` implementation, you will have to change the *adapter* registration whereas in the other way, you will have to change the *named* registration.

Functionally speaking, the two following registration are equivalent.

```
builder.RegisterDecorator<IHeaderMappingRepository>(
                      (c, inner) => new CachedHeaderMappingRepository(inner), 
                      fromKey: "headerMappingRepository")
       .As<IHeaderMappingRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<SqlHeaderMappingRepository>()
       .Named<IHeaderMappingRepository>("headerMappingRepository");


builder.Register(c => new CachedHeaderMappingRepository(
                      c.ResolveNamed<IHeaderMappingRepository>("headerMappingRepository")))
       .As<IHeaderMappingRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<SqlHeaderMappingRepository>()
       .Named<IHeaderMappingRepository>("headerMappingRepository"));
```